# Remove the 300ms delay from phonegap apps

Tags: cordova, webkit

I have been trying to make my app more responsive, but unfortunately nothing seems to help.
I am using PhoneGap and hence I am experiencing the famous 300ms delay for touch events.

This makes the app feel very unresponsive and slow which is just not an option.

I saw some libraries like Fastclick.js that solve this issue for jQuery mobile users, but I am not using jQuery mobile. I am making my app just using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery.

I really need to find a way to get rid of that 300ms delay for my touch clicks.
Looking forward to any help I can get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Christophe Coenraets has addressed this issue in his [*Top 10 Performance Techniques for PhoneGap Applications*](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/05/top-10-performance-techniques-for-phonegap-applications/). It's the #6 and the video is available on [Adobe TV](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2013/top-10-performance-techniques-for-phonegap-applications/) (at the 31st minute).

Basically, the 300ms delay is not a bug or a performance issue, it's a feature necessary to detect the possible *double tap*.

The solution to get rid of that delay is to use a combination of [`touch` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) instead of the `click` event with something like this :

```js
var trackingClick = false;
var targetElement = null;
var touchStartX = 0;
var touchStartY = 0;
var touchBoundary = 10;

target.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {

    trackingClick = true;
    targetElement = event.target;
    touchStartX = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
    touchStartY = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;

    return true;
});

target.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {

    trackingClick = false;

    //handle click event
    ...

    return false;
});

target.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    if (!trackingClick) {
        return true;
    }

    // If the touch has moved, cancel the click tracking
    if (targetElement !== event.target 
        || (Math.abs(event.changedTouches[0].pageX - touchStartX) > touchBoundary 
        || (Math.abs(event.changedTouches[0].pageY - touchStartY) > touchBoundary)) {
        trackingClick = false;
        targetElement = null;
    }

    return true;
});

target.addEventListener('touchcancel', function() {
    trackingClick = false;
    targetElement = null;
});
```

But that's basically what [*FastClick*](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) is doing (in fact, the above snippet is just a very basic example ripped off of [fastclick source code](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/blob/master/lib/fastclick.js)). There are lots of other cases to handle so if you don't feel like implementing your own library, you should really take a closer look at FastClick. It's not only for *jQuery mobile* users, in fact, it doesn't even need jQuery, it's just a self-contained small footprint library.

*Note for jQuery mobile users : you can use FastClick but you should be aware of the built-in similar feature : [vclick](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/)*

**tl;dr : use [*FastClick*](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) if you don't have jQuery Mobile**

Comment: Thanks for this info. 
I added fastclick.js to my project, and added window.addEventListener('load', function() {        FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false); to the deviceReady function, but still nothing. No improvement. :/ Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: @alwaysStuck It's really hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the entire code. You should post some code (ideally a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), possibly in a new question.

Comment: I think your answer is correct for my initial question. The only problem is probably my code that crashes something somewhere, but as that wasn't a part of the initial question, I am marking your answer as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: May be some one can hack UIWebView - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155560/cordova-disabling-the-click-delay-300ms-click-delay-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 5):

Fastclick is not working for me.
Maybe it doesn't support Phonegap or the webview that it's using.

The only way to fix the 300ms delay in Phonegap/cordova:

```
$('yourElement').on( 'touchstart', function ( startEvent ) {});
```

instead of onclick. Any other solutions, including fastclick didn't work in Phonegap.

Comment: Yep, exactly the same problem and it makes complete sense... Solution, use fast click :p

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with a super minimal solution after some problems with fastclick when triggering click events. This example uses jQuery.

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '.clickable', function(e){
    // This prevents the click to be completed
    // so will prevent the annoying flickering effect
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You have to add .clickable class to any element you want to take out the 300m delay from.

Then, change all click events for touchstart events, so this

```
$('#elementid').click(function(e){
   console.log('ex event'); 
}
```

has to be now this

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '#elementid', function(e){
   console.log('new event'); 
}
```

Comment: your solution was useful. Nice explanation!