# mobile chrome vs safari performance

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I am working on mobile hybrid application based on phonegap/cordova.
web code is based on angular. I am facing various performance issues when I work with chrome on android. same code works smooth with safari on ios app.

typical performance issue is if you tap on link it will take miliseconds more to react and navigate. Also transition/animation is slower than ios.

IOS 6 or above
android 4.4 or above

I want to know what is slowing down my web code in chrome setup. Is there some myth or reason why it should slowdown?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no explicit reason that it should be slower. However, there is most probably some performance difference between devices and in general I've found iOS devices a little more responsive in that sense but new Androids (>= 4.4) feel quite the same.

What you probably are facing with the links reacting slowly is the [famous 300ms delay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19317649/1744702) for double-tap detection capability which can be removed by binding to *touchstart* instead of *click* as mentioned on first answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks 300ms one is good solution. Also for  < 4.4 (android) I found crosswalk helpful.

Comment: Yes, Crosswalk won't probably hurt performance-wise but keep in your mind that it is huge package compared to plain app.