# Delay when tapping Select field in Cordova iOS app

Tags: html, ios, iphone, cordova, touch

When a user taps a select box in my Cordova iOS app, there is a (~500ms) delay before the select options are displayed.

Notes:

- I'm well aware of the regular iOS tap delay, but I believe that this is a different (though I'm sure related) issue.
- Using the same HTML/CSS, the issue does *not* appear in iOS Safari! Tapping the select, shows the options immediately.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317649/remove-the-300ms-delay-from-phonegap-apps)

Comment: I will look into that further however, I did mention that 1) I'm well aware of such things and 2) This works properly on iOS Safari. What would account for the difference in behavior on Safari vs Cordova?

Comment: If you aren't using WKWebView, that would be one big difference. Mobile Safari uses the newer WKWebView, and Cordova (by default) uses UIWebView, which is older. There are good reasons for that (WKWebView isn't a drop-in replacement), but it might explain the difference you're seeing.

Comment: What plugins (if any) do you have installed? What version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: @KerriShotts Thanks for that, I hadn't known about the WKWebView/UIWebView difference. I am going to do some further testing before I reply to your other questions and hopefully at least discover if this is indeed the reason for the difference.