# mouseup, mousedown, mousemove for iphone with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone

I just want something that behaves like a mouse clicking, dragging, and releasing on a screen (I'm using a canvas).

I tried ontouchmove/ontouchstart/ontouchcancel evewnts but I got a third of a second delay before they responded, ontouchstart would only trigger as my finger LEFT the area (followed immediately by ontouchcancel), and if I hold for much more than a second then secondary browser functions start activating.

The only thing I have gotten to work so far is using preventDefault in ontouchmove to prevent the screen from being dragged. This also makes it so ontouchstart activates immediately, though there is 1/3 second before ontouchcancel triggers if I release quickly (adding meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" didn't help) and if I drag then ontouchcancel NEVER activates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove-the-300ms-delay-from-phonegap-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317649/remove-the-300ms-delay-from-phonegap-apps)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the 300ms delay from phonegap apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317649/remove-the-300ms-delay-from-phonegap-apps)

Comment: The 300ms delay is by far the least annoying thing. For example, I currently seem to have the option of either it not detecting a press until the release event happens or not being able to drag objects rendered in my canvas because it drags the whole screen. Also, I don't want to use jquery.